# aspx dropdown adding items how to get dropdownlist instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I want to add items to my drop down in function addItems. How to do that at runtime?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownNum" runat="server" Width="50px" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("num")%>' OnLoad='addItems'>
</asp:DropDownList>

protected void addItems() {
    ...
    foreach (NumOption option in ConfigManager.Config.NumOptions.Options)
    {
        numDropDown.Items.Add(option.Value);
    }
}
```

edit: I need to get the instance of the DropDownList to call it via numDropDown, the adding itself is not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add items like...

```
numDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Text", "Value"));
```

Edit: In reference your comments, you are unable to get the Control reference in your code class. You have to find the control in the particular container e.g.

```
DropDownList numDropDown = (DropDownList)Container.Item.FindControl("DropDownNum");
```

**Note:** where Container is the control in your dropdownlist

Comment: the problem i have is how to get the instance of the dropdownlist into numDropDown

Comment: You can get like... DropDownList numDropDown = DropDownNum;

Comment: I can't get the instance by DropDownList numDropDown = DropDownNum; I've to define what DropDownNum is an therefore I need an instance of the control.

Answer (score -1):

```
numDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("text", option.Value));
```

Comment: adding is not the problem, need to get an instance of the control where I want to add the items.

Comment: You should have said that before. My answer was as per your question. No need to negate my answer.